# I accidentally removed read, write and execute permissions from the root ("/") directory

Tags: raspbian, boot, permissions

I hope you have a solution for that: I wanted to remove permissions to a specific folder with:

```
sudo chmod -rwx ./
```

But instead I had executed:

```
sudo chmod -rwx /
```

so I had removed all permissions to the root directory instead of the current folder.

Now I don't have access to any command, including `sudo`. I am on a rpi 4 running on Raspberry PI OS (Raspbian). I have a lot of important things, a pro website with a database. I have one or two backups of one database but not the others... I have a few importants programs without backups.

The OS does not boot actually.

Thank you if you can help me!

Comment: If you do things like this expect to break your OS. Restore from your backup. You COULD try mounting on a Linux OS and fix permissions.

Comment: @Milliways The damage is not that bad, he only removed permissions from a single folder. If it was `chmod -R`, then restoring from backup would make more sense.

Comment: Hint: next time, use `.` instead of `./` - it's shorter to type and harder to make a problematic typo that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue that cannot be corrected out of the running system. I would advise shutting down the Pi<sup>(1)</sup>, removing the SD card and then attaching it via card-reader to a different computer running Linux (if you have one available). In the following steps, I will call that machine the "recovery machine".

<sup>(1)</sup> since you probably can't call `shutdown` anymore, you have to either try an ordered shutdown via the [Magic SysRq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) keystroke <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, or if that fails, you will need to perform a hard power-off instead

On your recovery machine:

- Identify the device if necessary. To do so, you could e.g. execute

  ```
  ~ # journalctl -f
  ```

  as `root` user on your "recovery" machine and check for an entry like

  ```
  Okt 29 18:58:31 my-machine kernel: sd 33:0:0:0: [sdb] 62333948 512-byte logical blocks: (31.9 GB/29.7 GiB)
  Okt 29 18:58:31 my-machine kernel:  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
  ```

  that coincides with your plugging in the SD card. Assuming a standard Raspbian disk layout, the relevant device containing the root partition would be `/dev/sdb2`.
- As `root` on the recovery machine, perform an `fsck` on the partitions of the SD card before mounting any of them:

  ```
  ~ # fsck -v /dev/sdb1
  (fsck output)
  ~ # fsck -v /dev/sdb2
  (fsck output)
  ```
- Mount the root partition of the SD card. It should be the second partition:

  ```
  ~ # mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
  ```

  If you execute an `ls` command in the root directory *of your recovery machine*, the entry for the `/mnt` mount-point will then look something like

  ```
  / # ls -l
  <...>
  d---------  18 root root  4096 Mar 14  2021 mnt
  ```

  reflecting the completely removed permissions on the `/` partition of your SD card.
- Re-add the necessary permissions via

  ```
  / # chmod 755 /mnt
  ```

  If you run `ls` again, the entry should look more familiar, like

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x  18 root root  4096 Mar 14  2021 mnt
  ```
- Afterwards, `unmount`, plug the card back in the Pi, and boot. It should work again (mainly because it seems that you didn't *recursively* revoke the `rwx` permissions).

Comment: A slight departure from your excellent solution is to utilize `chmod` capability to clone/copy permissions from one file or directory to another using the `--reference` option. See `man chmod` for details.